# Material-UI change TextField color when input text is too long

Tags: css, material-ui

I am new to Material UI and I am currently testing on TextField.

When the value is longer that the width of the field, you still can read the text with clicking on the field and drag to right.
I would like to ask if there is a way to change the font color (Or any other thing) if length of the string is longer than a certain value in order to indicate there are some texts left behind.

(Single line edit field is necessary since there are many fields required to show on screen)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Setting the `error` property on the `FormControl` and using a `FormHelperText` isn't enough?

Comment: Thank you for you reply.Yes, the use case actually is not an error case, it is caused by the field is not big enough to show all the string. So I would like to see if there is any way to add an indicator to the field to indicate all the string cannot be shown. The idea is when the indicator is on, tooltips will add to the field and show the full string.